# C# reflection and Func<object,bool> member

Tags: c#, .net, reflection

I have 3 classes, each of which has the same function fields:

```
class A {
    Func<sampleobject,bool> alpha = c=>c.some1 == something;
    Func<sampleobject,bool> beta = c=>c.some1 == something;
}
class B {
    Func<sampleobject,bool> alpha = c=>c.some1 == something;
    Func<sampleobject,bool> beta = c=>c.some1 == something;
}
class C {
    Func<sampleobject,bool> alpha = c=>c.some1 == something;
    Func<sampleobject,bool> beta = c=>c.some1 == something;
}
```

I have a factory that will get me the proper class. There's also another method that will determine which function of the class gets called.

```
dbcontext.sampleobjects.where(Factory(class).ReflectionFunction(memberName));
```

I was able to use reflection to get the member name via:

```
var prop = this.GetType().GetMember("alpha");
```

I just don't know how to use this or what to call to be able to be used in the "WHERE" statement like if I would call it directly.

```
dbcontext.sampleobjects.Where(instanceofA.alpha);
```

Comment: I don't understand exactly what it is you're trying to do. As I understand it, you: Have a few classes which each have two `Func` members, each named `alpha` and `beta`; have an application where you want to be able to call the `alpha` or `beta` `Func` regardless of the containing class; have figured out how to get your `Func` of choice, but can't figure out how to use it or call it using some kind of LINQ query. Is this all correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var prop = this.GetType().GetMember("alpha");
```

is a bit misleading - it is a field, not a property. However, you can get its actual value with:

```
var func = (Func<sampleobject, bool>)prop.GetValue(this);
```

and then use it in the `Where` call:

```
dbcontext.sampleobjects.Where(func);
```

(or use it directly on an object like this:)

```
sampleobject obj = null; // or some other value
var result = func(obj);
```